Next.js 14 Server Action Not Returning Data to Client-Side Component
I use a server action for data fetching, and it should return data to the client component, but it's not working as expected.
Server action:
"use server";

import { getCookies } from "next-client-cookies/server";

export async function getData() {
    const cookie = getCookies();
    const token = cookie.get("access_token");
    const response = await fetch(url,{method: "GET", headers: {"Token" : token}});
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

Client component:
"use client";

export default function Component() {
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getDataFromServerAction() {
            const data = await getData();
            console.log(data); //nothing out
        }
    })
}

I try to remove "use server". It works but cannot get cookie.

Have you tried setting the return data to a state value and check if that works?

You are not calling the function you defined in the useEffect hook:
"use client";

export default function Component() {
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getDataFromServerAction() {
            const data = await getData();
            console.log(data); //nothing out
        }
        // Call the above function
        getDataFromServerAction();
    },[]) 
    // Empty dependency array since effect doesn't depend on reactive values
}

You can read more about server actions and mutations in the docs.

Thank you. I forgot to write call the function. But actually it doesn't work.

What part doesn't work? Would you like to set the state so that you can render it?

I think, your useEffect misses dependency array.
You can edit your client component
"use client";

 export default function Component() {
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getDataFromServerAction() {
            const data = await getData();
            console.log(data); //nothing out
           }
        }, [])
 }


Note that Thomas' answer similarly provides an empty dependency array, but also explicitly calls getDataFromServerAction.
